# VMware Infrastructure Web Access 2.0.0 stuck at "Loading"

Tags: vmware-vcenter

We have a Ubuntu 11 server running VMware virtual machines. We manage it using VMware Infrastructure Web Access 2.0.0. My colleague is able to use it successfully with Internet Explorer 9. However, I am stuck with an empty login page that says "Loading" in the title when trying to connect. It happens in all browsers (IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Opera). My colleague also gets stuck at "Loading" if he tries another browser.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it unacceptable that the program doesn't present any kind of error message that could guide you in the right direction, but after a lot of experimenting I found these steps worked:

- Use Internet Explorer. Unfortunately VMware Infrastructure Web Access 2.0.0 seems to be incompatible with other browsers, at least when using Windows. The console-login feature in the virtual machine view doesn't work with other browsers beside Firefox.
- Add the host part of the URL to VMware Infrastructure Web Access to "Trusted Sites" in Internet Explorer. Restart IE after doing this.
- You may have to click the compatibility view icon in the URL bar of IE to get the login screen to appear.